# Как в AS установить вreakpoint на изменение переменной

Tags: android, android-studio

Переменная странно себя ведет ... где-то меняет значение, хотя этого делать не должна. Все участки кода, где переменная используется обставил брекпоинтами. Ничего не помогает, уже мозг кипит.

Хочу установить брекпоинт на событие "смена значения" переменной. Есть ли такое в AS? Т.е. если переменная меняет значение - срабатывает брекпоинт.

upd: Watch знаю. Все равно не могу отследить. Нужно именно событие на смену значения.

upd2: Переменная типа int, зарегистрирована в Activity. По сути у нее есть два важнейших состояния, до вызова ContextMenu, переменная инициируется. После выбора действия в ContextMenu - переменная используется.

Работает все хорошо, пока не переворачиваешь экран. Начинаются какие-то чудеса.
Переменную также инициирую (до вызова ContextMenu), а вот после вызова ContextMenu ее значение обнуляется. Почему и кто это делает, понять не могу.

Еще раз повторю, до того как перевернули экран - все хорошо. В момент переворота экрана, все переменные аккуратно сохраняю и восстанавливаю когда Activity становится активной.

upd3.

Объявление в классе Activity:

```
int selectItemPosition = -1;
```

До Context Menu присваиваю значение:

```
selectItemPosition = (int) ib.getTag();
```

где ib - ImageButton. Тэг присваиваю ему в кастомном адаптере ListView, когда рисую данный ImageButton (он у меня в каждом пункте ListView присутствует). Именно ImageButton и вызывает контекстное меню.

После выбора в контекстном меню нужного действия, использую:

```
mainAdapter.setFavorite(selectItemPosition);
```

И вот как раз при использовании, selectItemPosition становится -1.
Хотя, до вызова контекстного меню, все было хорошо. selectItemPosition соответствовало позиции в списке, который вызвал меню.

Еще раз повторюсь. До поворота экрана все работает. А вот после поворота такая каша ...

Comment: Код объявления и изменения переменной приведите, а то будет гадание на кофейной гуще. А вообще это лучше называть полем класса.

Comment: Спасибо, исправлюсь :) Привел описание объявления поля, изменения и дальнейшего использования. Поворот экрана обрабатываю [вот так](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject) хотя этой переменной это не касается, но, например, адаптер так сохраняю.

Comment: После поворота экрана у вас видимо ImageView пересоздается а тэг ему заного не присваивается

Comment: Нет, в том то и дело. Значение присваивается перед ContextMneu и я его проверяю (тут все хорошо, ImageView хранит Tag). А вот потом, что-то происходит и после закрытия ContextMneu меняется значение ... не иначе как колдовство.

Comment: В общем нашел решение проблемы (но так и не понял что это было). В место поля типа int, создал класс, который содержит это поле и геттер и сеттер для доступа к нему. Добавил этот класс как поле в Activity и сохраняю этот класс при преобразовании Activity. Все стало работать и значения не меняются ...

Comment: эм, а зачем в класс то это было превращать? что мешало сам int сохранять?

Comment: Пробовал :( Если работать с int, то имею все те проблемы о которых писал. Как только запаковал в класс - все стало хорошо ... вот сижу и думаю, радоваться или плакать. Так как причины такого поведения не понимаю ...

Comment: вы что то не договариваете, такое поведение в принципе невозможно

Comment: Возможно. Просто сам не понимаю, что надо договорить (или посмотреть) чтобы решить задачу. В любом случае спасибо! Буду упражняться дальше :)

Comment: Воссоздал ситуацию и код на простом примере в [отдельной теме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554601/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-activity-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

Брекпоинты можно ставить только на конкретные строки. При этом можно задать им некоторые условия при которых они будут или не будут срабатывать. В вашем случае думаю наиболее удобно будет спрятать изменение переменной за сеттером, то есть изменять её только вызовом метода сеттера, поставить бряк внутри этого сеттера и либо бряку задать условие срабатывания - смена значения, либо просто дописать в тело метода условие и бряк ставить внутри этого условия.

Comment: Спасибо! Хороший способ - возьму на вооружение. Но тут ситуация иная (см. upd2), я знаю где переменная меняется у меня в коде ... но судя по всему что-то с ней происходит и я этим не управляю. Вот мне и надо понять окружение в момент изменения значения.