# Поведение поля класса Activity после поворота экрана

Tags: android, activity

Есть простой проект (полный листинг ниже).

В проекте,

- есть Activity с ListView. Каждый элемент списка представляет собой кнопку – нажатие на которую вызывает контекстное меню.
- в классе MainActivity есть поле tagButton, которое запоминает позицию элемента у которого нажали кнопку.
- Адаптер кастомный, внутри адаптера прорисовываются пункты меню и полю Tag кнопки присваивается позиция конкретного пункта списка.
- При повороте экрана сохраняется адаптер [с помощью фрагмента](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)

До поворота экрана все работает (нажатие на кнопку -> сохранение позиции в tagButton -> отображение меню –> получение корректного tagButton).

А вот если повернуть экран, получается что-то мне непонятное: нажатие на кнопку -> **сохранение корректной позиции в tagButton** -> отображение меню –> **получение не корректного tagButton**?!

Что происходит между “сохранение корректной позиции в tagButton” и “получение не корректного tagButton”?

PS. Если tagButton завернуть в простой класс и изменять/получать значение с помощью сеттера/ геттера и при этом сохранять экземпляр класса через фрагмент (при повороте экрана) то все хорошо.

PPS. Алгоритм получения ошибки:

1. Запускаем приложение.
2. Нажимаем любую кнопку (например, 3), появляется меню. В логах: Tag before: 3
3. Выбираем пункт меню. В логах Tag after: 3
4. Переворачиваем экран.
5. Нажимаем любую кнопку (например, 2), появляется меню. **В логах: Tag before: 2**
6. Выбираем пункт меню. **В логах Tag after: -1**

Код MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import layout.SaveFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int tagButton = -1;
    LvAdapter adapter;
    SaveFragment saveStateFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        saveStateFragment = (SaveFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SAVE");
        if (saveStateFragment != null) {

            adapter = saveStateFragment.getAdapter();
        } else
        {
            saveStateFragment = new SaveFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(saveStateFragment, "SAVE")
                    .commit();

            adapter = new LvAdapter(this);
        }
        tagButton = -1;
        ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1)).setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        tagButton = (int) ((Button) v).getTag();
        Log.d("err", "Tag before: " + String.valueOf(tagButton));
        menu.add("Получить Tag");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("err", "Tag after: " + String.valueOf(tagButton));
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        saveStateFragment.setAdapter(adapter);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Код адаптера:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LvAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int count = 100;
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;

    public LvAdapter (Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        }

        final Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        btn.setTag(i);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity activity = (Activity) ctx;
                activity.registerForContextMenu(btn);
                activity.openContextMenu(btn);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Код фрагмента:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import biz.temp.LvAdapter;

public class SaveFragment extends Fragment {

    LvAdapter adapter;

    public LvAdapter getAdapter() {
        return adapter;
    }

    public void setAdapter(LvAdapter adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}
```

Разметка Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка пункта списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что проблема в адаптере. У вас запросто может слететь ссылка на контекст, к тому же при каждом нажатии на кнопку, у вас создается новая ссылка, и только в этом случае сетится контекстное меню.И это кажется мне странным. При использовании, например, `RecyclerView` вам просто хватило бы из `ViewHolder` доставать кнопку из каждого элемента, и сетить там, без пробрасывания и переприсваивания ссылок.

Answer (score 2):

После поворота у вас адаптер остаётся старым так как зачем то сохранен в retain фрагменте, но при это он хранит в себе ссылку на экземпляр старой активити и работает с ним. Удивительно что у вас тут не крашится всё нафиг когда вызываются методы старой активити.

В общем вот вам советы:

1. НИКОГДА не сохраняйте ссылку на активити, фрагмент, контекст (не считая Aplication) и сервис в класс который будет жить дольше этих компонент если в нем не предусмотрено удаление этой ссылки в случае деактивации того компонента. В противном случае непонятные краши это самое лучшее что вам обеспечено. В худшем убьёте часы если не дни на поиски проблемы из за которой приложение ведет себя как то странно.
2. setRetainInstance придумал дьявол, сохранять состояние через такие фрагменты чревато многими проблемами. Для сохранения состояния есть onSaveInstanceState, если данных для сохранения много, то скорее всего их необходимо сохранять на диск в SharedPrefereces, базу данных или просто в файл. setRetainInstance имел некоторый смысл при работе с асинк тасками, но они сами по себе очень неудобные и на разных версиях андройда ведут себя сильно по разному, так что опытные разработчики их уже давно не используют ибо есть куча проверенных, популярных и очень удобных альтернатив.

Comment: Да. действительно, проблема была в Activity. Я переписал класс адаптера и Activity. Сейчас они взаимодействуют через интерфейс. На сколько я понимаю это правильный и безопасный способ взаимодействия?

Comment: И правильность и безопасность такого способа полностью зависят от реализации)

Answer (score 0):

Переписал класс Activity и Адаптера. В частности, сейчас они взаимодействуют через интерфейс `onSetButtonClickListener`. При таком подходе все работает ...

Класс Адаптера:

```
    public class LvAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public interface onSetButtonClickListener {
        public void setButtonClickListener(Button btn);
    }

    onSetButtonClickListener iActivity;

    public void setSetClickListener(onSetButtonClickListener iActivity) {
        this.iActivity = (onSetButtonClickListener) iActivity;
    }

    int count = 100;
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;

    public LvAdapter (Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        }

        final Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        btn.setTag(i);

        iActivity.setButtonClickListener(btn);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Класс Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LvAdapter.onSetButtonClickListener {

    int tagButton = -1;
    LvAdapter adapter;
    SaveFragment saveStateFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        saveStateFragment = (SaveFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SAVE");
        if (saveStateFragment != null) {

            adapter = saveStateFragment.getAdapter();
        } else
        {
            saveStateFragment = new SaveFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(saveStateFragment, "SAVE")
                    .commit();

            adapter = new LvAdapter(this);
        }
        tagButton = -1;
        adapter.setSetClickListener(this);
        ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1)).setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        tagButton = (int) ((Button) v).getTag();
        Log.d("err", "Tag before: " + String.valueOf(tagButton));
        menu.add("Получить Tag");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("err", "Tag after: " + String.valueOf(tagButton));
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        saveStateFragment.setAdapter(adapter);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void setButtonClickListener(Button btn) {
        registerForContextMenu(btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openContextMenu(view);
            }
        });
    }
}
```